# flink: scala version conflict?

Tags: java, scala, intellij-idea, apache-flink

Am attempting to compile the kafka sample from [here](https://github.com/dataArtisans/kafka-example) in IntelliJ. After much fussing with dependencies have run into this issue that I can't seem to get past:

```
15/10/25 12:36:34 ERROR actor.ActorSystemImpl: Uncaught fatal error from thread [flink-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4] shutting down ActorSystem [flink]
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/runtime/AbstractPartialFunction$mcVL$sp
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:455)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:367)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.MemoryArchivist.handleMessage(MemoryArchivist.scala:80)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.FlinkActor$class.receive(FlinkActor.scala:32)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.MemoryArchivist.org$apache$flink$runtime$LogMessages$$super$receive(MemoryArchivist.scala:59)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.LogMessages$class.receive(LogMessages.scala:26)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.MemoryArchivist.receive(MemoryArchivist.scala:59)
at akka.actor.ActorCell.newActor(ActorCell.scala:567)
at akka.actor.ActorCell.create(ActorCell.scala:587)
at akka.actor.ActorCell.invokeAll$1(ActorCell.scala:460)
at akka.actor.ActorCell.systemInvoke(ActorCell.scala:482)
at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processAllSystemMessages(Mailbox.scala:282)
at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:223)
at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.exec(Mailbox.scala:234)
at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)


Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction$mcVL$sp
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
... 28 more
```

I've run across a few notions that suggest this is an issue with the scala version. Current library list:

```
flink-runtime-1.0-SNAPSHOT
flink-streaming-java-1.0-SNAPSHOT
flink-connector-kafka-1.0-SNAPSHOT
flink-java8-1.0-SNAPSHOT
flink-core-1.0-SNAPSHOT
flink-java-1.0-SNAPSHOT
org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-core:1.2.1
flink-clients-1.0-SNAPSHOT
org.apache.kafka:kafka-clients:0.8.2.2
org.apache.kafka:kafka_2.11:0.8.2.2
flink-optimizer-1.0-SNAPSHOT
org.apache.sling:org.apache.sling.commons.json:2.0.6
de.javakaffee:kryo-serializers:0.28
com.github.scopt:scopt_2.11:3.3.0
org.clapper:grizzled-slf4j_2.9.0:0.6.6
com.typesafe.akka:akka-osgi_2.11:2.4.0
com.typesafe.akka:akka-slf4j_2.11:2.4.0
```

Suggestions on where I've run astray?

Comment: Which OS are you running?

Comment: OSX 10.10.5 ---> why?

Comment: java -version
java version "1.8.0_25"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_25-b17)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.25-b02, mixed mode)

Comment: I was thinking that it could be a java version issue (you were running an older java). Anyway just confirm scala is not seeing an older java

run `scala`
then 
`util.Properties.versionString`
and then
`util.Properties.javaVersion`

Comment: scala> util.Properties.versionString
res0: String = version 2.11.6

scala> util.Properties.javaVersion
res1: String = 1.8.0_25

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is indeed a Scala version mismatch. You're mixing dependencies which are built for Scala `2.11`, e.g. `org.apache.kafka:kafka_2.11:0.8.2.2` with Flink dependencies which are built by default for Scala `2.10`.

One of the dependencies built for Scala `2.11` pulls in the `scala-library:2.11` jar which replaces the `scala-library:2.10` dependency required by the Flink dependencies. You either use the binaries built for Scala `2.10` for the non-Flink dependencies or you build and install Flink using Scala `2.11`. See https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-master/setup/building.html#build-flink-for-a-specific-scala-version for how to build Flink with different Scala version.

#### Kafka example

If you just want to bump the version of the referenced Kafka example to `0.10-SNAPSHOT` you have to change the Flink version in the `pom.xml` file and you have to use the `FlinkKafkaProducer` instead of the `KafkaSink` in the `WriteIntoKafka.java` file. You don't need the `SimpleStringSchema` then anymore. That is all you have to change (no additional dependencies are required).

Comment: In this case I just copied the java for the kafka-reader from the site and (attempted to) wrap flink-0.10-SNAPSHOT around it.  I think I've flushed out all the references to scala 2.10 but I'm still seeing this error. Will keep looking.

Comment: @ethrbunny, what do you mean with flushing out all references to Scala `2.10`? If you pull the Flink dependencies from maven central, then you need Scala `2.10`. Maybe you can share your `pom.xml`, then I could see what you tried.